# Will there be any compatibility issue if i upgrade my Databricks run time version

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Will there be any issue in my current notebooks and jobs if i upgrade my Databricks run time version from 9.1 LTS to 10.4 LTS

I didn't tried upgrading the version. If I upgrade it then will I be able to change it back to previous version

Comment: Did you check the official documentation from Databricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a very broad question - exact answer depends on the features and libraries/connectors that you're using in your code. You can refer to the [Databricks Runtime 10.x migration guide](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/10.x-migration.html) and [Spark 3.2.1 migration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/migration-guide.html) for more information about upgrade.

Usually, the correct way to do is to try to run your job with new runtime, but using the test environment, where your production data won't be affected.

Comment: Will I be able to change back to previous version after upgrading if i need?

Comment: usually yes, it really depends on what functionality you're using

Comment: Just another doubt not related with this question,is it possible to drop column in delta table?

Comment: My requirement is that in my delta table i need to delete one column and add another with same name but different type . My run time version is 9.2 and i found some article showing drop column work in version 10 and above

Comment: yes, it's possible to drop a column from Delta table: https://delta.io/blog/2022-08-29-delta-lake-drop-column/, but if you look into documetation you'll see that it's supported starting with 11.0: https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-column-mapping.html#drop-columns.

Comment: what about reading all data, remoing column, and write back in the overwrite mode?

Comment: It is not working for me. I tried using overwrite schema method

Comment: While I tried to use overwriteSchema method i am getting error that ' failed to merge fields '

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249107/discussion-between-farzu-and-alex-ott).